# Xlint:deprecation Warning

Tags: windows-7, java, cmd

```
import java.text.ParseException; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Age
{
   public static void main(String []args)
     {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int daysInMon[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30,31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};  //Days in month
        int days, month, year;
        char[] dob = new char[110];

    System.out.println("Please Enter your Day of Birth(1-31): ");
        days = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter your Month of Birth(1-12): ");
        month = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter your Year of Birth(1900): ");
        year = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your Date of Birth: "+days+ "/" +month+ "/" +year);

    Date d = new Date();

        System.out.println("Current Date: " +d.getDate()+ "/" +(d.getMonth()+1)+ "/" +(d.getYear()+1900));

        days = daysInMon[month - 1] - days + 1;

        days = days + d.getDate();
        month = (12 - month) + d.getMonth();
        year = (d.getYear() + 1900) - year - 1;

        if (month >= 12)
        {
        year = year + 1;
        month = month - 12;
        }


        System.out.println("Age:" +year+ "years" +month+ "months" +days+ "days");
     }
}
```

This is my code to generate the Age according to the keyboard input. When I compile through cmd I shows two notes. Then I recompile using `-Xlint` it shows:

```
Xlint:deprecation Warning
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note: Age.java uses or overrides a deprecated API, Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.

Comment: D:\Kamal>javac Age.java
Note: Age.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

D:\Kamal>javac -Xlint Age.java
Age.java:34: warning: [deprecation] getDate() in Date has been deprecated
        days = days + d.getDate();
                       ^
Age.java:35: warning: [deprecation] getMonth() in Date has been deprecated
        month = (12 - month) + d.getMonth();
                                ^
Age.java:36: warning: [deprecation] getYear() in Date has been deprecated
        year = (d.getYear() + 1900) - year - 1;
                 ^
3 warnings

Comment: it's deprecation, not desperation

Answer (score 0):

These deprecated methods are being used, which bring up the deprecation warning:

```
d.getDate()
d.getMonth()
d.getYear()
```

If you want to avoid the deprecation warnings, use these methods instead.

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

See the [Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for more details.